# SVM with multiple features

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, svm

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn import svm


X=[[1,0,0,0,0],
           [0,1,0,0,0],
           [0,0,1,0,0],
           [1,0,0,1,0],
           [1,0,0,0,1]] 

y=[0,1,1,1,0]

model=svm.SVC()
model.fit(X,y)
print(model.predict([1,0,1,0,0]))
```

I was working on this but Iam getting an error as

```
"if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1. 0. 1. 0. 0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single fe
ature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Iam new to this can u guys help me out?

Answer (score 2):

After having performed

```
X=np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],
           [0,1,0,0,0],
           [0,0,1,0,0],
           [1,0,0,1,0],
           [1,0,0,0,1]])

y=np.array([0,1,1,1,0])
```

you have to do the following:

```
y = y.reshape(1, -1)

model=svm.SVC()
model.fit(X,y)
test = np.array([1,0,1,0,0])
test = test.reshape(1,-1)
print(model.predict(test))
```

In future you have to scale your dataset. You can use either Standard Scaler (suggested) or MinMax Scaler.

Comment: I guess `print(model.predict([1,0,1,0,0]))` should be `print(model.predict(np.array([[1,0,1,0,0]])))`, maybe :) Idon't have possibility to check right now

Comment: did you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are lists but they need to be arrays.

```
X=np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],
           [0,1,0,0,0],
           [0,0,1,0,0],
           [1,0,0,1,0],
           [1,0,0,0,1]])

y=np.array([0,1,1,1,0])
```